# Bootstrap Container Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Below you will find my bootstrap 4 code. On the bottom of the code, you will see "why is this section not bellow the video"

I can't seem to figure out why that code is not in a new section below the code.

I know this is a user issue, I just cant seem to figure out why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
/* font-family: 'Paytone One', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif; */

.questrial {
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}


/* .green-back{
    background: rgb(215,255,206);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(215,255,206,1) 5%, rgba(186,202,224,1) 100%);
    height: 95vh;
    margin: 1em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    } */

.navbar-brand {
  padding-left: 2%;
}

.logoImg {
  height: 2em;
  width: auto;
}

video {
  /* width: 100%    !important;
    height: auto   !important; */
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.navbar {
  margin-top: 3vh;
  margin: 1em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);
}

.space {
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}

.headBtn {
  height: 70%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.signUpBtn,
.signInBtn {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#signIn {
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
  border: 1px solid #7b7b7b;
  font: bold;
}

#signUp {
  background-color: rgb(145, 145, 145);
  border: 1px solid #7b7b7b;
  color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-brand.abs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}

.headingIntro {
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: #79787A;
  padding-top: 10vh;
}

.headingMain {
  font-size: 5vw;
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

.headingContent {
  font-size: 2vw;
  color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
}

.heroButton {
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 20vw;
}

.heroButton:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.charityText {
  padding-top: 1%;
}

.heroTextBack {
  background-color: rgb(245, 245, 245, .8);
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .heroButton {
    margin-top: 10%;
    width: 20vw;
  }
  .headingIntro {
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: #79787A;
    padding-top: 4vh;
  }
  .headingMain {
    font-size: 7vw;
    color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  }
  .headingContent {
    font-size: 4vw;
    color: rgb(65, 65, 65);
  }
  .btn-primary {
    background-color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
  }
  .charityText {
    padding-top: 1%;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    padding-left: 0%;
  }
  /* .buttonGrp{
    display: inline;
    } */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>meetlete: meet your favorite atheletes!</title>
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Paytone+One&family=Questrial&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="conatiner green-back">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
                            <source src="https://meetlete.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/FP000091HD01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="https://meetlete.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/FP000091HD01.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                            Your browser does not support the video tag.
                          </video>

        <!-- <video playsinline autoplay muted loop
                    src="https://meetlete.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/FP000091HD01.mp4">
                </video> -->
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <!-- Navbear -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-light justify-content-center questrial">
          <a href="./index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto">
            <img src="./assets/images/meetlete.png" class="logoImg">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                        </span>
                    </button>

          <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Learn
                                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About
                                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact
                                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto w-100 justify-content-end">
              <li class="nav-item headBtn">
                <button class="nav-link" id="signIn" href="#">Sign In
                                </button>
              </li>
              <li class="space headBtn">
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item headBtn">
                <button class="nav-link" id="signUp" href="#">Sign Up
                                </button>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container heroTextBack">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2 class="text-center headingIntro questrial">Introducing Meetlete (beta)</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h1 class='headingMain questrial'>Meet your favorite athlete!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-10 text-center questrial">
          <h3 class="headingContent">As a fan, how many opportunities do you get to have a real conversation with one of your favorite players or sports personalities?</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row questrial">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center buttonGrp">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary heroButton">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 text-center buttonGrp">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success heroButton">Talent</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row questrial">
        <div class="col-12">
          <p class='text-center charityText'>A porition of each Meetlete goes to charity!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">Why is this not bellow the video</div>
    </div>
  </div>






  <!-- <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light myFont">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                        <img src="./assets/images/meetlete-logo-text.png" height="40px" alt="CoolBrand">
                    </a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
                                    </li>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav> -->




  <!-- bootstrap js file-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What is your question? What result do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is  bcuz yow video tag has a position fixed which means that it does not belongs to the dom

Comment: Yep, when I removed the fixed in the css it no longer spans across the screen. Now I need to figure out how to make it look right in the background.

Comment: But what do you mean by right ? Do you have an screenshot or could you tell me a lil more